# How to retrieve data table from SQLite in C++?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm working with Sqlite in C++ and I'm going to write a function which takes a string as the select query command and return a vector of data as the data table.

The function looks something like this:

```
DataTable Select(const char *query);
```

And the DataTable is a typedef:

```
typedef vector<vector<void*>> DataTable;
```

I decided to use void* since the function must work on any select query command and in this case the column type is not predictable.

In the definition of the Select function I have:

```
DataTable Select(const char *query)
{
    int ret;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(m_Db, qStr, strlen(query), &stmt, 0);
    int nSize= sqlite3_column_count(stmt);

    DataTable dt;

    if (nSize> 0)
    {
        int type;
        int nRow = -1;

        do
        {
            ret = sqlite3_step(qStmt);
            if (ret == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                nRow++;
                dt.push_back(vector<void*>());

                for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++)
                {
                    type= sqlite3_column_type(stmt, 0);

                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case SQLITE_INTEGER:
                        {
                            dt[nRow].push_back(sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, i));
                        }
                        break;
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        } while (ret == SQLITE_ROW);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

My problem is that I cannot push any data to the DataTable vector.

```
dt[nRow].push_back(sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, i));
```

Maybe I should not use vector at all. please guide me on how to deal with this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: If you use `void*` how will you know what the type is later? Why not use SQLite's API directly? You'll end up wrapping quite a bit of it (memory allocation, type tracking, etc.) for mostly syntactical differences.

Comment: How to use the SQLite's API directly? Please be a little more specific.

Comment: I meant using `sqlite3_step`, `sqlite3_column_type`, etc. instead of wrapping everything with your own version (not that there's no value in wrapping it, just that the effort required seems high for the value gained -- but I don't know your use case, so I may of course be missing something).

Comment: I'm actually using the sqlite3_step, sqlite3_column_type. My problem is I don't know how properly retrieve the data into a data table containing rows and columns so that being able to pass a select query and get a data table.

Comment: Yes, I meant *instead* of creating a data table and then later consuming it, just consume directly from SQLite and cut out the middleman. I was simply wondering if you have a compelling reason to want a data table in the first place :-)

Comment: Now I need to ask you whether there is any specific type so that I can return data directly from sqlite. Maybe I'm not aware of it or of how to implement it.